# Parser RSS and correct visualization in table view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, text, rss, styles

In my application I use a parser in order to load data from rss. When I insert them in table, using the text allignment center, I do not obtain the correct visualization for me. I want obtain result like Reeder app.

My Code:

```
// Summary cell.textLabel.text = summaryString; 
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; 
// Multiline cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter; 
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:15];
```

This is my table

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/quYOM.png]

and this is Reeder style

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKNAK.png]

Comment: i don't have 10reputation yet to show entire code! :(

Comment: @Bruno.cf 

`// Summary
    cell.textLabel.text = summaryString;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Multiline
                cell.textLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
                cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
               cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:15];`

Comment: Ask me If you have another part of code to solve my question ..

Comment: Ciao Mattia, did you find any solution to show feeds like Reeder does?

Comment: yep :D the solutions are: Readability API or Readbility custom URL. More info on www.readability.com for API/URL. 

personally i've used custom url, filtering my url, like this-->             

`read_url= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.readability.com/m?url=%@", _entry.articleUrl];`